# Gocode tool error

Tags: git, go

I want to install gocode but whenever i try the command: go get -u github.com/nsf/gocode
    I get the error below:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
autocompletecontext.go
autocompletefile.go
decl.go
emacs-company/README.md
emacs-company/company-go.el
package.go
package_bin.go
package_text.go
utils.go

Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.Aborting Updating 46e8fd2..5070dac package github.com/nsf/gocode: exit status 1
```

so how do i force merge or overwrite the listed files. Thanks

Comment: which version of go do you use ?

Comment: Unrelated to Go: A simple git problem.

Comment: I'm using version 1.7.                                                                                          i wanted to add autocomplete plugin to Atom editor for GOLANG, and it requires gocode before the plugin can work.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why do you have changes on the `gocode` repository but you can do one of two things, depending of what you want.

**You don't care about your local changes:**

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/nsf/gocode
git checkout -- .
go get -u github.com/nsf/gocode
```

Here you are deleting your local changes and then updating `gocode`, so you don't have merge conflicts anymore.

**You want to keep your local changes for some reason:**

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/nsf/gocode
git stash
go get -u github.com/nsf/gocode
git stash apply
```

Here you are [stashing](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) your changes and applying them again after updating the code.